# What Happend To Pokkle After Neferpitou Stuck Those Antennas In His Head

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

We all know that the chimera ants found pokkle hiding under human skulls and Neferpitou stuck antennas into Pokkles head, but what i'm wondering is what happend to pokkle after that. So here are the options I think that happend...

- So did they feed him to the queen, and if they did, did he become a chimera ant or did he become a part of the king chimera ant (Meruem)?
- or did they just let hime die in the cave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Chapter 198** of the manga, Neferpitou told one of his subordinates that he doesn't need Pokkle anymore and **he should offer him to the Queen right away**. Pokkle was then chopped up but him being fed to the Queen was never depicted in the manga. It was also never shown that he became a Chimera Ant.